# Hilt - How to create module where a method throws an exception? Error: @Provides methods may only throw unchecked exceptions

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to implement Hilt by creating a `Module` class that provides `EncryptedSharedPreferences`

I'm getting the compile time error `@Provides methods may only throw unchecked exceptions` in my Provide method.

This is because when creating an `EncryptedSharedPreferences` it requires

`MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC)` for one of it's parameters. This method throws two exception types `GeneralSecurityException` and `IOException`.

How do I correctly provide the `SharedPreferences` in my module?

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent.class)
public class SharedPrefModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    SharedPreferences provideEncryptedSharedPreferences(@ApplicationContext Context context)
            throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        return EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
                "secret_shared_prefs",
                MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC),
                context,
                EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
                EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
        );
    }
}
```

**______________________________________________________________**

I've tried moving the `Master key` string to a seperate provides method into a try catch, but the error is still thrown during compile time.

```
@Provides
    @Singleton
    SharedPreferences provideEncryptedSharedPreferences(@ApplicationContext Context context, String masterKey)
            throws Exception{
        return EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
                "secret_shared_prefs",
                masterKey,
                context,
                EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
                EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
        );
    }

    @Provides
    String provideMasterKey() throws Exception {
        try {
            return MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC);
        }catch (Exception e){
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }
```

Not quite sure what to do.

Comment: The goal of dependency injection is to separate construction logics from the application's functional logics. So business logic exception should not be thrown in objection creations with Dagger but outside. I'm sure your code can be refactor to throw that same exception elsewhere, can it?

Comment: How would you pass the Exception to a module? The ```EncryptedSharedPreferences``` is injected into my ```LocalRepository``` and that is injected into my ```ViewModel```. ```Exception e = new RuntimeException();``` If I created this inside the constructor of my ```LocalRepository``` how do I give it to the module to create the ```EncryptedSharedPreferences```. Can you give some example code?

Answer (score 2):

I was throwing the wrong exception when wrapping it with a `try catch`. `Exception e` won't work, but using `RunTimeException` works.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent.class)
public class SharedPrefModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    SharedPreferences provideEncryptedSharedPreferences(@ApplicationContext Context context) {
        try {
            return EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
                    "secret_shared_prefs",
                    MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC),
                    context,
                    EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
                    EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create encrypted shared preferences");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct answer.